# Agilizar tiempo de respuesta

Tags: sql, aplicación-web

me encuentro realizando consultas a una base de datos vía web pero los tiempos de
respuesta son muy largos y enviaba el mensaje **GATEWAY TIME OUT**, modifique el archivo
postgresql.conf en los siguiente parametros:

```
**shared_buffers** tenìa 24 MB, lo actualice a **1GB**

**El tiempo de respuesta mejoro.**

**Desafortunadamente** me falta modificar algún otro parámetro porque vuelve a mostrar, en 
algunas ocasiones, **GATEWAY TIMEOUT**
```

`Verifique los tiempos de respuesta de las consultas y el resultado en el siguiente:`
db=# \timing

```
db=# SELECT subest,date(fecha_24), to_char(fecha_24,' HH24:MI') as HH_MM,valor FROM t_mediciones WHERE subest='EDO' AND fecha_24:text LIKE '2021-02-01 01:11%' ORDER BY fecha_24 ;

**RESULTADO:** 

subest=EDO
date= 2021-02-01 
hh_mm= 01:11
valor= -219.65

**Time: 261.116 ms**
El total de registro con los que cuenta la tablas, son:

db=#SELECT relpages, reltuplas FROM pg_class WHERE relname=`t_mediciones;

**relpages=5219
reltupla=527605**

El tiempo de respuesta a las consultas volvió a crecer y regreso a mostrar el mensaje: GATEWAY 
TIMEOUT

Agradeceré enormemente su apoyo para mejorar los tiempo de respuesta y no volver a mostrar el 
mensaje:  **GATEWAY TIMEOUT**

Respetos para Ustedes.
```

Comment: ¿La tabla que estás consultando tiene índices? Puedes compartir su estructura  incluyendo la definición de índices? Lo que estás realizando no debería ser tardado.

Comment: Gracias por responder, si tiene índices. Claro que si te comparto la estructura.

Comment: Column Type Modifiers
subestacion character(5) 
fecha character(26) 
valor numeric(6,2) 
fecha_24 timestamp without time zone 
index: "idx1_medcev" btree(subestacion,fecha)  
index: "idx2_medcev" btree(subestacion,fecha_24)

Answer (score 0):

Al buscar por una columna `timestamp` usando `LIKE` y tambien convertirla a text degrada la performance del indice por ser un valor parcial y al ser convertido a texto. Ya que al parecer que la columna si esta indexada, puedes intentar usar una expresion con BETWEEN en vez del LIKE, lo que hara usar el indice `idx2_medcev` sin necesidad de conversion:

```
SELECT subest,date(fecha_24), to_char(fecha_24,' HH24:MI') as HH_MM,valor 
FROM t_mediciones WHERE subest='EDO' 
AND fecha_24 BETWEEN '2021-02-01 01:11:00' AND '2021-02-01 01:11:59'
ORDER BY fecha_24 ;
```